# Rails Ajax dropdown menu - no response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I've solved almost all my problems with this little program I'm writing:

The only one left, that I'm just beating my head against, goes like this.

It's your standard two dropdown menus, select an item on one to populate the other.

In my view:

```
<%= 
  select_tag(  
      :contractor_id,
      options_from_collection_for_select(Contractor.all, "id", "appointment_record"), 
      :'data-remote' => 'true', 
      :'data-url' => url_for(:controller => 'contractors', :action => 'getdata'), 
      :'data-type' => 'json') 
%>


<%= 
   select_tag(
       :company_id, # name of selectbox
       )
%>
```

In my controller:

```
    def getdata
    @data_from_select1 = params[:contractor_id]

    @data_for_select2 = Company.where(:id => @data_from_select1).all

    # render an array in JSON containing arrays like:
    # [[:id1, :name1], [:id2, :name2]]
    render :json => @data_for_select2.map{|c| [c.id, c.name]}
  end
```

In my application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#contractor_id').live('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr) {

    var selectbox2 = $('#company_id');

    selectbox2.empty();

    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      // append an option
      var opt = $('<option/>');

      // value is an array: [:id, :name]
      opt.attr('value', value[0]);
      // set text
      opt.text(value[1]);
      // append to select
      opt.appendTo(selectbox2);
    });
  });
});
```

In my routes:

```
   get 'getdata' => 'contractors#getdata'
```

And I just don't get anything at all populating company.id. Not ever!

Contractor.id populates just fine, all the names fill out there, but nothing is returned to company.id

I'm a huge noobie, so I'm sure I'm missing something here. What??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the options in a different way? for example

```
           var selectbox2 = $('#company_id');

           var option = document.createElement("option");
       //Adds the value
           option.value = value[0];
       // Adds in text
           option.innerHTML = value[1];
       // Appends the option to you select box
           selectbox2[0].appendChild(option);
```

You can console.log(value); and see if you are getting a populated response or not.